# problem with sIFR 3 not displaying in IE just getting XXX

Tags: javascript, flash, sifr

I am having a problem with sIFR 3 not displaying in IE. I get 3 larges black XXX in IE yet it displays fine in Firefox. I have checked i do have the most recent version of flash installed correctly.

Here is the code on the page

```
        <div id="features">
        <div id="mainmessage_advertisers"><h2>Advertisers</h2><br /><br /><h3><a href="">Reach your customers where they browse. Buy directly from top web publishers.</a></h3><br /><br /><br /><a href=""><img src="img/buyads.gif" border="0"></a></div>

        <div id="mainmessage_publishers"><h2>Publishers</h2><br /><br /><h3>Take control of your ad space and start generating more revenue than <u>ever before</u>.</h3><br /><br /><br /><a href=""><img src="img/sellads.gif" border="0"></a></div>
        </div>`
```

Here is the code from my global.css

```
    #mainmessage_advertisers {
width: 395px;
height: 200px;
padding: 90px 50px;
border: 1px;
float: left;
}

#mainmessage_publishers {
width: 395px;
height: 200px;
padding: 90px 50px;
float: right;
}
```

and here is what i have in my sifr.js

```
/***********************************************************************
    SIFR 3.0 (BETA 1) FUNCTIONS
************************************************************************/

var parseSelector=(function(){var _1=/\s*,\s*/;var _2=/\s*([\s>+~(),]|^|$)\s*/g;var _3=/([\s>+~,]|[^(]\+|^)([#.:@])/g;var _4=/^[^\s>+~]/;var _5=/[\s#.:>+~()@]|[^\s#.:>+~()@]+/g;function parseSelector(_6,_7){_7=_7||document.documentElement;var _8=_6.split(_1),_9=[];for(var i=0;i<_8.length;i++){var _b=[_7],_c=toStream(_8[i]);for(var j=0;j<_c.length;){var _e=_c[j++],_f=_c[j++],_10="";if(_c[j]=="("){while(_c[j++]!=")"&&j<_c.length){_10+=_c[j]}_10=_10.slice(0,-1)}_b=select(_b,_e,_f,_10)}_9=_9.concat(_b)}return _9}function toStream(_11){var _12=_11.replace(_2,"$1").replace(_3,"$1*$2");if(_4.test(_12)){_12=" "+_12}return _12.match(_5)||[]}function select(_13,_14,_15,_16){return (_17[_14])?_17[_14](_13,_15,_16):[]}var _18={toArray:function(_19){var a=[];for(var i=0;i<_19.length;i++){a.push(_19[i])}return a}};var dom={isTag:function(_1d,tag){return (tag=="*")||(tag.toLowerCase()==_1d.nodeName.toLowerCase())},previousSiblingElement:function(_1f){do{_1f=_1f.previousSibling}while(_1f&&_1f.nodeType!=1);return _1f},nextSiblingElement:function(_20){do{_20=_20.nextSibling}while(_20&&_20.nodeType!=1);return _20},hasClass:function(_21,_22){return (_22.className||"").match("(^|\\s)"+_21+"(\\s|$)")},getByTag:function(tag,_24){return _24.getElementsByTagName(tag)}};var _17={"#":function(_25,_26){for(var i=0;i<_25.length;i++){if(_25[i].getAttribute("id")==_26){return [_25[i]]}}return []}," ":function(_28,_29){var _2a=[];for(var i=0;i<_28.length;i++){_2a=_2a.concat(_18.toArray(dom.getByTag(_29,_28[i])))}return _2a},">":function(_2c,_2d){var _2e=[];for(var i=0,_30;i<_2c.length;i++){_30=_2c[i];for(var j=0,_32;j<_30.childNodes.length;j++){_32=_30.childNodes[j];if(_32.nodeType==1&&dom.isTag(_32,_2d)){_2e.push(_32)}}}return _2e},".":function(_33,_34){var _35=[];for(var i=0,_37;i<_33.length;i++){_37=_33[i];if(dom.hasClass([_34],_37)){_35.push(_37)}}return _35},":":function(_38,_39,_3a){return (pseudoClasses[_39])?pseudoClasses[_39](_38,_3a):[]}};parseSelector.selectors=_17;parseSelector.pseudoClasses={};parseSelector.util=_18;parseSelector.dom=dom;return parseSelector})();
var sIFR=new function(){var _3b=this;var _3c="sIFR-active";var _3d="sIFR-replaced";var _3e="sIFR-flash";var _3f="sIFR-ignore";var _40="sIFR-alternate";var _41="sIFR-class";var _42="sIFR-layout";var _43="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";var _44=6;var _45=126;var _46=8;var _47="SIFR-PREFETCHED";var _48=" ";this.isActive=false;this.isEnabled=true;this.hideElements=true;this.replaceNonDisplayed=false;this.preserveSingleWhitespace=false;this.fixWrap=true;this.registerEvents=true;this.setPrefetchCookie=true;this.cookiePath="/";this.domains=[];this.fromLocal=true;this.forceClear=false;this.forceWidth=true;this.fitExactly=false;this.forceTextTransform=true;this.useDomContentLoaded=true;this.debugMode=false;this.hasFlashClassSet=false;var _49=0;var _4a=false,_4b=false;var dom=new function(){this.getBody=function(){var _4d=document.getElementsByTagName("body");if(_4d.length==1){return _4d[0]}return null};this.addClass=function(_4e,_4f){if(_4f){_4f.className=((_4f.className||"")==""?"":_4f.className+" ")+_4e}};this.removeClass=function(_50,_51){if(_51){_51.className=_51.className.replace(new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+_50+"(\\s|$)"),"").replace(/^\s+|(\s)\s+/g,"$1")}};this.hasClass=function(_52,_53){return new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+_52+"(\\s|$)").test(_53.className)};this.create=function(_54){if(document.createElementNS){return document.createElementNS(_43,_54)}return document.createElement(_54)};this.setInnerHtml=function(_55,_56){if(ua.innerHtmlSupport){_55.innerHTML=_56}else{if(ua.xhtmlSupport){_56=["<root xmlns=\"",_43,"\">",_56,"</root>"].join("");var xml=(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(_56,"text/xml");xml=document.importNode(xml.documentElement,true);while(_55.firstChild){_55.removeChild(_55.firstChild)}while(xml.firstChild){_55.appendChild(xml.firstChild)}}}};this.getComputedStyle=function(_58,_59){var _5a;if(document.defaultView&&document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){_5a=document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(_58,null)[_59]}else{if(_58.currentStyle){_5a=_58.currentStyle[_59]}}return _5a||""};this.getStyleAsInt=function(_5b,_5c,_5d){var _5e=this.getComputedStyle(_5b,_5c);if(_5d&&!/px$/.test(_5e)){return 0}_5e=parseInt(_5e);return isNaN(_5e)?0:_5e};this.getZoom=function(){return _5f.zoom.getLatest()}};this.dom=dom;var ua=new function(){var ua=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();var _62=(navigator.product||"").toLowerCase();this.macintosh=ua.indexOf("mac")>-1;this.windows=ua.indexOf("windows")>-1;this.quicktime=false;this.opera=ua.indexOf("opera")>-1;this.konqueror=_62.indexOf("konqueror")>-1;this.ie=false/*@cc_on || true @*/;this.ieSupported=this.ie&&!/ppc|smartphone|iemobile|msie\s5\.5/.test(ua)/*@cc_on && @_jscript_version >= 5.5 @*/;this.ieWin=this.ie&&this.windows/*@cc_on && @_jscript_version >= 5.1 @*/;this.windows=this.windows&&(!this.ie||this.ieWin);this.ieMac=this.ie&&this.macintosh/*@cc_on && @_jscript_version < 5.1 @*/;this.macintosh=this.macintosh&&(!this.ie||this.ieMac);this.safari=ua.indexOf("safari")>-1;this.webkit=ua.indexOf("applewebkit")>-1&&!this.konqueror;this.khtml=this.webkit||this.konqueror;this.gecko=!this.webkit&&_62=="gecko";this.operaVersion=this.opera&&/.*opera(\s|\/)(\d+\.\d+)/.exec(ua)?parseInt(RegExp.$2):0;this.webkitVersion=this.webkit&&/.*applewebkit\/(\d+).*/.exec(ua)?parseInt(RegExp.$1):0;this.geckoBuildDate=this.gecko&&/.*gecko\/(\d{8}).*/.exec(ua)?parseInt(RegExp.$1):0;this.konquerorVersion=this.konqueror&&/.*konqueror\/(\d\.\d).*/.exec(ua)?parseInt(RegExp.$1):0;this.flashVersion=0;if(this.ieWin){var axo;var _64=false;try{axo=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7")}catch(e){try{axo=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6");this.flashVersion=6;axo.AllowScriptAccess="always"}catch(e){_64=this.flashVersion==6}if(!_64){try{axo=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")}catch(e){}}}if(!_64&&axo){this.flashVersion=parseFloat(/([\d,?]+)/.exec(axo.GetVariable("$version"))[1].replace(/,/g,"."))}}else{if(navigator.plugins&&navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"]){var _65=navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"];this.flashVersion=parseFloat(/(\d+\.?\d*)/.exec(_65.description)[1]);var i=0;while(this.flashVersion>=_46&&i<navigator.mimeTypes.length){var _67=navigator.mimeTypes[i];if(_67.type=="application/x-shockwave-flash"&&_67.enabledPlugin.description.toLowerCase().indexOf("quicktime")>-1){this.flashVersion=0;this.quicktime=true}i++}}}this.flash=this.flashVersion>=_46;this.transparencySupport=this.macintosh||this.windows;this.computedStyleSupport=this.ie||document.defaultView&&document.defaultView.getComputedStyle&&(!this.gecko||this.geckoBuildDate>=20030624);this.css=true;if(this.computedStyleSupport){try{var _68=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];_68.style.backgroundColor="#FF0000";var _69=dom.getComputedStyle(_68,"backgroundColor");this.css=!_69||/\#F{2}0{4}|rgb\(255,\s?0,\s?0\)/i.test(_69);_68=null}catch(e){}}this.xhtmlSupport=!!window.DOMParser&&!!document.importNode;this.innerHtmlSupport;try{var n=dom.create("span");if(!this.ieMac){n.innerHTML="x"}this.innerHtmlSupport=n.innerHTML=="x"}catch(e){this.innerHtmlSupport=false}this.zoomSupport=!!(this.opera&&document.documentElement);this.geckoXml=this.gecko&&(document.contentType||"").indexOf("xml")>-1;this.requiresPrefetch=this.ieWin||this.khtml;this.verifiedKonqueror=false;this.supported=this.flash&&this.css&&(!this.ie||this.ieSupported)&&(!this.opera||this.operaVersion>=8)&&(!this.webkit||this.webkitVersion>=412)&&(!this.konqueror||this.konquerorVersion>3.5)&&this.computedStyleSupport&&(this.innerHtmlSupport||!this.khtml&&this.xhtmlSupport)};this.ua=ua;var _6b=new function(){function capitalize($){return $.toUpperCase()}this.normalize=function(str){if(_3b.preserveSingleWhitespace){return str.replace(/\s/g,_48)}return str.replace(/(\s)\s+/g,"$1")};this.textTransform=function(_6e,str){switch(_6e){case "uppercase":str=str.toUpperCase();break;case "lowercase":str=str.toLowerCase();break;case "capitalize":var _70=str;str=str.replace(/^\w|\s\w/g,capitalize);if(str.indexOf("function capitalize")!=-1){var _71=_70.replace(/(^|\s)(\w)/g,"$1$1$2$2").split(/^\w|\s\w/g);str="";for(var i=0;i<_71.length;i++){str+=_71[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+_71[i].substring(1)}}break}return str};this.toHexString=function(str){if(typeof (str)!="string"||!str.charAt(0)=="#"||str.length!=4&&str.length!=7){return str}str=str.replace(/#/,"");if(str.length==3){str=str.replace(/(.)(.)(.)/,"$1$1$2$2$3$3")}return "0x"+str};this.toJson=function(obj){var _75="";switch(typeof (obj)){case "string":_75="\""+obj+"\"";break;case "number":case "boolean":_75=obj.toString();break;case "object":_75=[];for(var _76 in obj){if(obj[_76]==Object.prototype[_76]){continue}_75.push("\""+_76+"\":"+_6b.toJson(obj[_76]))}_75="{"+_75.join(",")+"}";break}return _75};this.convertCssArg=function(arg){if(!arg){return {}}if(typeof (arg)=="object"){if(arg.constructor==Array){arg=arg.join("")}else{return arg}}var obj={};var _79=arg.split("}");for(var i=0;i<_79.length;i++){var $=_79[i].match(/([^\s{]+)\s*\{(.+)\s*;?\s*/);if(!$||$.length!=3){continue}if(!obj[$[1]]){obj[$[1]]={}}var _7c=$[2].split(";");for(var j=0;j<_7c.length;j++){var $2=_7c[j].match(/\s*([^:\s]+)\s*\:\s*([^\s;]+)/);if(!$2||$2.length!=3){continue}obj[$[1]][$2[1]]=$2[2]}}return obj};this.extractFromCss=function(css,_80,_81,_82){var _83=null;if(css&&css[_80]&&css[_80][_81]){_83=css[_80][_81];if(_82){delete css[_80][_81]}}return _83};this.cssToString=function(arg){var css=[];for(var _86 in arg){var _87=arg[_86];if(_87==Object.prototype[_86]){continue}css.push(_86,"{");for(var _88 in _87){if(_87[_88]==Object.prototype[_88]){continue}css.push(_88,":",_87[_88],";")}css.push("}")}return escape(css.join(""))}};this.util=_6b;var _5f={};_5f.fragmentIdentifier=new function(){this.fix=true;var _89;this.cache=function(){_89=document.title};function doFix(){document.title=_89}this.restore=function(){if(this.fix){setTimeout(doFix,0)}}};_5f.synchronizer=new function(){this.isBlocked=false;this.block=function(){this.isBlocked=true};this.unblock=function(){this.isBlocked=false;_8a.replaceAll()}};_5f.zoom=new function(){var _8b=100;this.getLatest=function(){return _8b};if(ua.zoomSupport&&ua.opera){var _8c=document.createElement("div");_8c.style.position="fixed";_8c.style.left="-65536px";_8c.style.top="0";_8c.style.height="100%";_8c.style.width="1px";_8c.style.zIndex="-32";document.documentElement.appendChild(_8c);function updateZoom(){if(!_8c){return}var _8d=window.innerHeight/_8c.offsetHeight;var _8e=Math.round(_8d*100)%10;if(_8e>5){_8d=Math.round(_8d*100)+10-_8e}else{_8d=Math.round(_8d*100)-_8e}_8b=isNaN(_8d)?100:_8d;_5f.synchronizer.unblock();document.documentElement.removeChild(_8c);_8c=null}_5f.synchronizer.block();setTimeout(updateZoom,54)}};this.hacks=_5f;var _8f={kwargs:[],replaceAll:function(){for(var i=0;i<this.kwargs.length;i++){_3b.replace(this.kwargs[i])}this.kwargs=[]}};var _8a={kwargs:[],replaceAll:_8f.replaceAll};function isValidDomain(){if(_3b.domains.length==0){return true}var _91="";try{_91=document.domain}catch(e){}if(_3b.fromLocal&&sIFR.domains[0]!="localhost"){sIFR.domains.unshift("localhost")}for(var i=0;i<_3b.domains.length;i++){if(_3b.domains[i]=="*"||_3b.domains[i]==_91){return true}}return false}this.activate=function(){if(!ua.supported||!this.isEnabled||this.isActive||!isValidDomain()){return}this.isActive=true;if(this.hideElements){this.setFlashClass()}if(ua.ieWin&&_5f.fragmentIdentifier.fix&&window.location.hash!=""){_5f.fragmentIdentifier.cache()}else{_5f.fragmentIdentifier.fix=false}if(!this.registerEvents){return}function handler(evt){_3b.initialize();if(evt&&evt.type=="load"){if(document.removeEventListener){document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",handler,false);document.removeEventListener("load",handler,false)}if(window.removeEventListener){window.removeEventListener("load",handler,false)}}}if(window.addEventListener){if(_3b.useDomContentLoaded&&ua.gecko){document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",handler,false)}window.addEventListener("load",handler,false)}else{if(ua.ieWin){if(_3b.useDomContentLoaded&&!_4a){document.write("<scr"+"ipt id=__sifr_ie_onload defer src=//:></script>");document.getElementById("__sifr_ie_onload").onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState=="complete"){handler();this.removeNode()}}}window.attachEvent("onload",handler)}}};this.setFlashClass=function(){if(this.hasFlashClassSet){return}dom.addClass(_3c,dom.getBody()||document.documentElement);this.hasFlashClassSet=true};this.removeFlashClass=function(){if(!this.hasFlashClassSet){return}dom.removeClass(_3c,dom.getBody());dom.removeClass(_3c,document.documentElement);this.hasFlashClassSet=false};this.initialize=function(){if(_4b||!this.isActive||!this.isEnabled){return}_4b=true;_8f.replaceAll();clearPrefetch()};function getSource(src){if(typeof (src)!="string"){if(src.src){src=src.src}if(typeof (src)!="string"){var _95=[];for(var _96 in src){if(src[_96]!=Object.prototype[_96]){_95.push(_96)}}_95.sort().reverse();var _97="";var i=-1;while(!_97&&++i<_95.length){if(parseFloat(_95[i])<=ua.flashVersion){_97=src[_95[i]]}}src=_97}}if(!src&&_3b.debugMode){throw new Error("sIFR: Could not determine appropriate source")}if(ua.ie&&src.charAt(0)=="/"){src=window.location.toString().replace(/([^:]+)(:\/?\/?)([^\/]+).*/,"$1$2$3")+src}return src}this.prefetch=function(){if(!ua.requiresPrefetch||!ua.supported||!this.isEnabled||!isValidDomain()){return}if(this.setPrefetchCookie&&new RegExp(";?"+_47+"=true;?").test(document.cookie)){return}try{_4a=true;if(ua.ieWin){prefetchIexplore(arguments)}else{prefetchLight(arguments)}if(this.setPrefetchCookie){document.cookie=_47+"=true;path="+this.cookiePath}}catch(e){if(_3b.debugMode){throw e}}};function prefetchIexplore(_99){for(var i=0;i<_99.length;i++){document.write("<embed src=\""+getSource(_99[i])+"\" sIFR-prefetch=\"true\" style=\"display:none;\">")}}function prefetchLight(_9b){for(var i=0;i<_9b.length;i++){new Image().src=getSource(_9b[i])}}function clearPrefetch(){if(!ua.ieWin||!_4a){return}try{var _9d=document.getElementsByTagName("embed");for(var i=_9d.length-1;i>=0;i--){var _9f=_9d[i];if(_9f.getAttribute("sIFR-prefetch")=="true"){_9f.parentNode.removeChild(_9f)}}}catch(e){}}function getRatio(_a0){if(_a0<=10){return 1.55}if(_a0<=19){return 1.45}if(_a0<=32){return 1.35}if(_a0<=71){return 1.3}return 1.25}function getFilters(obj){var _a2=[];for(var _a3 in obj){if(obj[_a3]==Object.prototype[_a3]){continue}var _a4=obj[_a3];_a3=[_a3.replace(/filter/i,"")+"Filter"];for(var _a5 in _a4){if(_a4[_a5]==Object.prototype[_a5]){continue}_a3.push(_a5+":"+escape(_6b.toJson(_6b.toHexString(_a4[_a5]))))}_a2.push(_a3.join(","))}return _a2.join(";")}this.replace=function(_a6,_a7){if(!ua.supported){return}if(_a7){for(var _a8 in _a6){if(typeof (_a7[_a8])=="undefined"){_a7[_a8]=_a6[_a8]}}_a6=_a7}if(!_4b){return _8f.kwargs.push(_a6)}if(_5f.synchronizer.isBlocked){return _8a.kwargs.push(_a6)}var _a9=_a6.elements;if(!_a9&&parseSelector){_a9=parseSelector(_a6.selector)}if(_a9.length==0){return}this.setFlashClass();var src=getSource(_a6.src);var css=_6b.convertCssArg(_a6.css);var _ac=getFilters(_a6.filters);var _ad=(_a6.forceClear==null)?_3b.forceClear:_a6.forceClear;var _ae=(_a6.fitExactly==null)?_3b.fitExactly:_a6.fitExactly;var _af=_ae||(_a6.forceWidth==null?_3b.forceWidth:_a6.forceWidth);var _b0=parseInt(_6b.extractFromCss(css,".sIFR-root","leading"))||0;var _b1=_6b.extractFromCss(css,".sIFR-root","background-color",true)||"#FFFFFF";var _b2=_6b.extractFromCss(css,".sIFR-root","opacity",true)||"100";if(parseFloat(_b2)<1){_b2=100*parseFloat(_b2)}var _b3=_6b.extractFromCss(css,".sIFR-root","kerning",true)||"";var _b4=_a6.gridFitType||_6b.extractFromCss(css,".sIFR-root","text-align")=="right"?"subpixel":"pixel";var _b5=_3b.forceTextTransform?_6b.extractFromCss(css,".sIFR-root","text-transform",true)||"none":"none";var _b6="";if(_ae){_6b.extractFromCss(css,".sIFR-root","text-align",true)}if(!_a6.modifyCss){_b6=_6b.cssToString(css)}var _b7=_a6.wmode||"";if(_b7=="transparent"){if(!ua.transparencySupport){_b7="opaque"}else{_b1="transparent"}}for(var i=0;i<_a9.length;i++){var _b9=_a9[i];if(!ua.verifiedKonqueror){if(dom.getComputedStyle(_b9,"lineHeight").match(/e\+08px/)){ua.supported=_3b.isEnabled=false;this.removeFlashClass();return}ua.verifiedKonqueror=true}if(dom.hasClass(_3d,_b9)||dom.hasClass(_3f,_b9)){continue}var _ba=false;if(!_b9.offsetHeight||!_b9.offsetWidth){if(!_3b.replaceNonDisplayed){continue}_b9.style.display="block";if(!_b9.offsetHeight||!_b9.offsetWidth){_b9.style.display="";continue}_ba=true}if(_ad&&ua.gecko){_b9.style.clear="both"}var _bb=null;if(_3b.fixWrap&&ua.ie&&dom.getComputedStyle(_b9,"display")=="block"){_bb=_b9.innerHTML;dom.setInnerHtml(_b9,"X")}var _bc=dom.getStyleAsInt(_b9,"width",ua.ie);if(ua.ie&&_bc==0){var _bd=dom.getStyleAsInt(_b9,"paddingRight",true);var _be=dom.getStyleAsInt(_b9,"paddingLeft",true);var _bf=dom.getStyleAsInt(_b9,"borderRightWidth",true);var _c0=dom.getStyleAsInt(_b9,"borderLeftWidth",true);_bc=_b9.offsetWidth-_be-_bd-_c0-_bf}if(_bb&&_3b.fixWrap&&ua.ie){dom.setInnerHtml(_b9,_bb)}var _c1,_c2;if(!ua.ie){_c1=dom.getStyleAsInt(_b9,"lineHeight");_c2=Math.floor(dom.getStyleAsInt(_b9,"height")/_c1)}else{if(ua.ie){var _bb=_b9.innerHTML;_b9.style.visibility="visible";_b9.style.overflow="visible";_b9.style.position="static";_b9.style.zoom="normal";_b9.style.writingMode="lr-tb";_b9.style.width=_b9.style.height="auto";_b9.style.maxWidth=_b9.style.maxHeight=_b9.style.styleFloat="none";var _c3=_b9;var _c4=_b9.currentStyle.hasLayout;if(_c4){dom.setInnerHtml(_b9,"<div class=\""+_42+"\">X<br />X<br />X</div>");_c3=_b9.firstChild}else{dom.setInnerHtml(_b9,"X<br />X<br />X")}var _c5=_c3.getClientRects();_c1=_c5[1].bottom-_c5[1].top;_c1=Math.ceil(_c1*0.8);if(_c4){dom.setInnerHtml(_b9,"<div class=\""+_42+"\">"+_bb+"</div>");_c3=_b9.firstChild}else{dom.setInnerHtml(_b9,_bb)}_c5=_c3.getClientRects();_c2=_c5.length;if(_c4){dom.setInnerHtml(_b9,_bb)}_b9.style.visibility=_b9.style.width=_b9.style.height=_b9.style.maxWidth=_b9.style.maxHeight=_b9.style.overflow=_b9.style.styleFloat=_b9.style.position=_b9.style.zoom=_b9.style.writingMode=""}}if(_ba){_b9.style.display=""}if(_ad&&ua.gecko){_b9.style.clear=""}_c1=Math.max(_44,_c1);_c1=Math.min(_45,_c1);if(isNaN(_c2)||!isFinite(_c2)){_c2=1}var _c6=Math.round(_c2*_c1);if(_c2>1&&_b0){_c6+=Math.round((_c2-1)*_b0)}var _c7=dom.create("span");_c7.className=_40;var _c8=_b9.cloneNode(true);for(var j=0,l=_c8.childNodes.length;j<l;j++){_c7.appendChild(_c8.childNodes[j].cloneNode(true))}if(_a6.modifyContent){_a6.modifyContent(_c8,_a6.selector)}if(_a6.modifyCss){_b6=_a6.modifyCss(css,_c8,_a6.selector)}var _cb=handleContent(_c8,_b5);if(_a6.modifyContentString){_cb=_a6.modifyContentString(_cb,_a6.selector)}if(_cb==""){continue}var _cc=["content="+_cb.replace(/\</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;"),"width="+_bc,"height="+_c6,"fitexactly="+(_ae?"true":""),"tunewidth="+(_a6.tuneWidth||""),"tuneheight="+(_a6.tuneHeight||""),"offsetleft="+(_a6.offsetLeft||""),"offsettop="+(_a6.offsetTop||""),"thickness="+(_a6.thickness||""),"sharpness="+(_a6.sharpness||""),"kerning="+_b3,"gridfittype="+_b4,"zoomsupport="+ua.zoomSupport,"filters="+_ac,"opacity="+_b2,"blendmode="+(_a6.blendMode||""),"size="+_c1,"zoom="+dom.getZoom(),"css="+_b6];_cc=encodeURI(_cc.join("&amp;"));var _cd="sIFR_callback_"+_49++;var _ce={flashNode:null};window[_cd+"_DoFSCommand"]=(function(_cf){return function(_d0,arg){if(/(FSCommand\:)?resize/.test(_d0)){var $=arg.split(":");_cf.flashNode.setAttribute($[0],$[1]);if(ua.khtml){_cf.flashNode.innerHTML+=""}}}})(_ce);_c6=Math.round(_c2*getRatio(_c1)*_c1);var _d3=_af?_bc:"100%";var _d4;if(ua.ie){_d4=["<object classid=\"clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000\" id=\"",_cd,"\" sifr=\"true\" width=\"",_d3,"\" height=\"",_c6,"\" class=\"",_3e,"\">","<param name=\"movie\" value=\"",src,"\"></param>","<param name=\"flashvars\" value=\"",_cc,"\"></param>","<param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\"></param>","<param name=\"quality\" value=\"best\"></param>","<param name=\"wmode\" value=\"",_b7,"\"></param>","<param name=\"bgcolor\" value=\"",_b1,"\"></param>","<param name=\"name\" value=\"",_cd,"\"></param>","</object>","<scr","ipt event=FSCommand(info,args) for=",_cd,">",_cd,"_DoFSCommand(info, args);","</","script>"].join("")}else{_d4=["<embed class=\"",_3e,"\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" src=\"",src,"\" quality=\"best\" flashvars=\"",_cc,"\" width=\"",_d3,"\" height=\"",_c6,"\" wmode=\"",_b7,"\" bgcolor=\"",_b1,"\" name=\"",_cd,"\" allowScriptAccess=\"always\" sifr=\"true\"></embed>"].join("")}dom.setInnerHtml(_b9,_d4);_ce.flashNode=_b9.firstChild;_b9.appendChild(_c7);dom.addClass(_3d,_b9);if(_a6.onReplacement){_a6.onReplacement(_ce.flashNode)}}_5f.fragmentIdentifier.restore()};function handleContent(_d5,_d6){var _d7=[],_d8=[];var _d9=_d5.childNodes;var i=0;while(i<_d9.length){var _db=_d9[i];if(_db.nodeType==3){var _dc=_6b.normalize(_db.nodeValue);_dc=_6b.textTransform(_d6,_dc);_d8.push(_dc.replace(/\%/g,"%25").replace(/\&/g,"%26").replace(/\,/g,"%2C").replace(/\+/g,"%2B"))}if(_db.nodeType==1){var _dd=[];var _de=_db.nodeName.toLowerCase();var _df=_db.className||"";if(/\s+/.test(_df)){if(_df.indexOf(_41)){_df=_df.match("(\\s|^)"+_41+"-([^\\s$]*)(\\s|$)")[2]}else{_df=_df.match(/^([^\s]+)/)[1]}}if(_df!=""){_dd.push("class=\""+_df+"\"")}if(_de=="a"){var _e0=_db.getAttribute("href")||"";var _e1=_db.getAttribute("target")||"";_dd.push("href=\""+_e0+"\"","target=\""+_e1+"\"")}_d8.push("<"+_de+(_dd.length>0?" ":"")+escape(_dd.join(" "))+">");if(_db.hasChildNodes()){_d7.push(i);i=0;_d9=_db.childNodes;continue}else{if(!/^(br|img)$/i.test(_db.nodeName)){_d8.push("</",_db.nodeName.toLowerCase(),">")}}}if(_d7.length>0&&!_db.nextSibling){do{i=_d7.pop();_d9=_db.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;_db=_d9[i];if(_db){_d8.push("</",_db.nodeName.toLowerCase(),">")}}while(i<_d9.length&&_d7.length>0)}i++}return _d8.join("").replace(/\n|\r/g,"")}};

sIFR.prefetch({
    src: 'swf/sifr/helvetica.swf'
});

sIFR.activate();

sIFR.replace({
selector: 'h2, h3', 
src: 'swf/sifr/helvetica.swf',
wmode: 'transparent',
css: {
    '.sIFR-root' : { 'color': '#000000', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'letter-spacing': '-1'  },
    'a': { 'text-decoration': 'none' },
    'a:link': { 'color': '#000000' },
    'a:hover': { 'color': '#000000' },
    '.span': { 'color': '#979797' },
    'label': { 'color': '#E11818' }
}
});

sIFR.replace({
selector: 'h4', 
src: 'swf/sifr/helvetica.swf',
wmode: 'transparent',
css: {
    '.sIFR-root' : { 'color': '#7E7E7E', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'letter-spacing': '-0.8'  },
    'a': { 'text-decoration': 'none' },
    'a:link': { 'color': '#7E7E7E' },
    'a:hover': { 'color': '#7E7E7E' },
    'label': { 'color': '#E11818' }
}
});

sIFR.replace({
selector: '#cart p', 
src: 'swf/sifr/helvetica-lt.swf',
wmode: 'transparent',
css: {
    '.sIFR-root' : { 'color': '#979797', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'letter-spacing': '-0.8'  },
    'a': { 'text-decoration': 'none' },
    'a:link': { 'color': '#979797' },
    'a:hover': { 'color': '#000000' },
    'label': { 'color': '#979797' }
}
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post an online example? That would be much easier to look at than trying to guess what's wrong from the code.

Comment: http://beta.advrtz.com/theme/index.php

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version is [r436](http://dev.novemberborn.net/sifr3/nightlies/) which doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upgrade to the latest version, the blog post [sIFR 3 and IE8 1.bottom JS error](http://people.bluechip.ro/arthur/sifr-3-and-ie8-1bottom-js-error/) has a possible fix:

> ... the solution is to set the font-size in px and not in em.